# wcf binding properties

Tags: wcf, binding, properties

What happens when WCF binding properties like MaxReceivedMessageSize, OpenTimeout, ReceiveTimeout, SendTimeout and Security on the client program have different values than server program ones? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Security settings: you will not be able to connect / execute operations if you use different security mechanisms. The server decides how it wants to control security, and the client has to conform to his demands.

Otherwise: nothing specific really. Of course when you run into a MessageSize boundary, or hit a timeout, the client will receive an exception message if it has happened on the server side, or generate an exception if it happened on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically in security, properties like SecurityMode (Message or Transport), ClientCredentialType (Message or Transport) must be match in server and client, or am I wrong??

Answer (score 0):

As C. Evenhuis said, the security stuff is determined by the server, but in general, you want to be careful with the other settings as well.  If the server will send a max size message of n bytes, then it doesn't help for the client to attempt to accept something much larger.

In my experience, a lot of engineers get confused when they try to increase one of these other settings on the client and don't get the result they're expecting.  This is usually because they forget about the relevant settings on the server side.

If you don't have a view into what settings the server is configured for (one of the few beefs I have with WCF), then it will be more difficult to know the boundaries you can set for your client.